# Doxygen pdf output: links for c++ classes in index don't work properly

Tags: c++, latex, doxygen

Peculiar problem. The page links in the TOC and in the Class Index at the top of the document work fine. Clicking on the hyperlinked page number takes you to the right place in the document.

However, in the index section at the very end of the document, the page links here take you to about where the class is documented, but always one or two pages before.

This would be confusing for someone who doesn't know this problem exists. Not sure where it comes from though - doxygen or latex.
I run latex twice (have tried running it more times, but this makes no difference).

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you post this to the Doxygen forum.

Comment: Looks like the problem described in bug_707483 in bugzilla.

Comment: The solution for bug 707483 will be specific for doxygen's user manual. If you see this for your own doxygen output (especially when using a standard stylesheet and refman.tex) then it is likely a different issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. The links in the TOC are a bit off (2-3 pages away)